# rbenv: command not found in Jenkins execute shell after moving to rbenv from RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rbenv

I moved to rbenv from RVM on Ubuntu Server.

When I use RVM, there is no trouble using bundle. After moving to rbenv I got a "command not found" error in Jenkins' execute shell.

I imploded and removed RVM and removed all RVM related lines from ~/.bashrc'. I still get this error after using:

```
rvm implode
rm ~/.rvm -rf
rm ~/.rvmrc 

gem install bundler
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

. ~/.bashrc

rbenv versions

jenkins@testserver:~/jobs/myjob/workspace$ rbenv versions

* 1.9.3-p374 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

Answer (score 12):

You seem to have installed rbenv correctly in your shell. However, if Jenkins doesn't source your `~/.bashrc` as well, it won't be aware there's rbenv on your system. So in Jenkins, you have to ensure that your PATH for executing commands also includes `$HOME/.rbenv/bin` and `$HOME/.rbenv/shims`.

There's no need to use `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in Jenkins; that's only useful for interactive shells.

Answer (score 3):

@mislav's answer is probably right, but what actually worked for me was this:

```
sh '''
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
rbenv local
rbenv rehash
'''
```

In fact, I wasn't seeing rbenv as `/usr/local/bin` wasn't in my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing the following

```
sh '''
#!/bin/bash
source ~/buildmac-init

bundle update
bundle exec fastlane build
'''
```

in this `buildmac-init` file (among other variables):

```
...
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
...
```